# Inner hits not working with nested filter?

Tags: elasticsearch

I've just upgraded to Elastic Search 1.5.0 and so far I can't make [inner_hits](http://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/1.x/search-request-inner-hits.html) work with a nested filter, although it works fine with a nested query.

Let's say I want to retrieve the inner nested object **actors** within a **movie** object.

When I run the following **nested query** :

**Syntax 1**

```
GET my_index/movie/_search
{
  "query": {
    "filtered": {
      "query": {"match_all": {}},
      "filter": {
        "nested": {
          "path": "actors",
          "query": {
            "match": {
              "actors.id": 12345
            }
          }, 
          "inner_hits" : {}
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

=> I get the inner_hits as documented [here](http://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/1.x/search-request-inner-hits.html), which is just fine.

But when I try doing the equivalent query with a **nested filter** :

**Syntax 2**

```
GET my_index/movie/_search
{
  "query": {
    "filtered": {
      "query": {"match_all": {}},
      "filter": {
        "nested": {
          "path": "actors",
          "filter": {
            "term": {
              "actors.id": 12345
            }
          }, 
          "inner_hits" : {}
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

=> I get the following parse error

> QueryParsingException[[my_index] [nested] requires either 'query' or
>   'filter' field]

(and this last query works fine when I remove inner_hits - except of course that I don't get the inner hits ...)

Is there something wrong in the syntax I use or is the inner_hits not implemented yet with nested filter ?

Thanks in advance

**Edit 3-30-2015**

It works with the syntax provided below by [@mdewit](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4101876/mdewit) (thanks!)

**Syntax 3**

```
GET my_index/movie/_search
{
    "query": {
        "nested": {
            "path": "actors",
            "query": {
                "filtered": {
                    "filter": {
                        "term": {"actors.id": 12345}
                    }
                }
            },
            "inner_hits" : {}
        }
    }
}
```

even though this syntax does not match the [Nested Filter doc](http://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/1.x/query-dsl-nested-filter.html)

=> I still do not understand what is wrong with Syntax 2. It seems like an ES bug to me.

**Edit 04-22-2015 : bug fixed** in ES 1.5.1, see my comment below

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Bug fixed in ElasticSearch 1.5.1 as stated [here](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/pull/10309)

So this syntax works (and works fine)

```
GET my_index/movie/_search
{
  "query": {
    "filtered": {
      "query": {"match_all": {}},
      "filter": {
        "nested": {
          "path": "actors",
          "filter": {
            "term": {
              "actors.id": 12345
            }
          }, 
          "inner_hits" : {}
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Thanks guys!

Answer (score 6):

The following seems to work:

```
GET my_index/movie/_search
{
    "query": {
        "nested": {
            "path": "actors",
            "query": {
                "filtered": {
                    "filter": {
                        "term": {"actors.id": 12345}
                    }
                }
            },
            "inner_hits" : {}
        }
    }
}'
```

Comment: Yep it works, thanks for that! Nevertheless, I'll leave the question open as the syntax you provided isn't exactly the one described in the official Nested Filter documentation : http://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/1.x/query-dsl-nested-filter.html
I still reckon there's something wrong in the error message I get from ES in the example I provided