# Elasticsearch inner_hits query results in ArrayOutOfBoundsException

Tags: elasticsearch, lucene

Ive been looking forward to the inner_hits capability introduced in elasticsearch 1.5 so decided to give it a try today. However, I keep getting an ArrayIndexOutOfBounds error when trying to use it. Im able to reproduce my problem with the following example:

My mapping:

```
curl -XPOST 'http://localhost:9200/_template/test' -d '
{
    "template": "testindex", 
    "mappings": {
        "testtype" : {
            "properties" : {
                "comments" : {
                    "properties": {
                        "subEntries": {
                            "type": "nested",
                            "properties": {
                                "message": {
                                    "type" : "string", 
                                    "index": "not_analyzed"
                                } 
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
'
```

My data:

```
curl -XPOST 'http://localhost:9200/testindex/testtype' -d '
{
    "comments": {
        "subEntries": [
            {"message": "Nice website"},
            {"message": "Worst ever"}
        ]
    }
}'
```

My query:

```
curl -XGET 'http://localhost:9200/testindex/testtype/_search' -d '
{
    "query": {
        "nested": {
            "path": "comments.subEntries",
            "query": {
                "match": {"comments.subEntries.message": "Nice website"}
            },
            "inner_hits" : {}
        }
    }
}'
```

Output:

```
{"took":12,"timed_out":false,"_shards":{"total":5,"successful":4,"failed":1,"failures":[{"index":"testindex","shard":3,"status":500,"reason":"ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException[-1]"}]},"hits":{"total":1,"max_score":1.4054651,"hits":[]}}
```

Note that if I drop inner_hits from the query, everything works as expected (the whole document gets returned):

Query #2:

```
curl -XGET 'http://localhost:9200/testindex/testtype/_search' -d '
{
    "query": {
        "nested": {
            "path": "comments.subEntries",
            "query": {
                "match": {"comments.subEntries.message": "Nice website"}
            }
        }
    }
}'
```

Output #2:

```
{"took":133,"timed_out":false,"_shards":{"total":5,"successful":5,"failed":0},"hits":{"total":1,"max_score":1.4054651,"hits":[{"_index":"testindex","_type":"testtype","_id":"AUxaX1RovKqomcXSCC2z","_score":1.4054651,"_source":
{
    "comments": {
        "subEntries": [
            {"message": "Nice website"},
            {"message": "Worst ever"}
        ]
    }
}}]}}
```

Im not sure what is wrong since I think Ive followed the documentation here correctly: [inner_hits reference](http://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/1.x/search-request-inner-hits.html) Please let me know what the issue might be.

Comment: In this question the person got it working with nested queries: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29251994/inner-hits-not-working-with-nested-filter

Comment: Not quite the same problem. In my case, the issue is that my nested object sits inside another object.

Answer (score 0):

This is verified to be a [bug](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/issues/10334) in elasticsearch 1.5.0. Will be fixed in future.

The bug occurs if the nested documents is inside a simple object. A workaround is to change the simple object to be a nested document as well. In this case, the mapping needs to change to:

```
curl -XPOST 'http://localhost:9200/_template/test' -d '
{
    "template": "testindex", 
    "mappings": {
        "testtype" : {
            "properties" : {
                "comments" : {
-->                 "type": "nested",
                    "properties": {
                        "subEntries": {
                            "type": "nested",
                            "properties": {
                                "message": {
                                    "type" : "string", 
                                    "index": "not_analyzed"
                                } 
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}'
```