# Elasticsearch: inner_hits does not work for nested queries (nested twice)

Tags: elasticsearch, nested

I'm using ES v1.5.2 (so [`inner_hits`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/1.x/search-request-inner-hits.html) is present and does work correctly for [filters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29251994/inner-hits-not-working-with-nested-filter)) and I have deeply nested documents in elasticsearch with nested paths :

- members
- members.members

This means that in the mapping (https://gist.github.com/frickm/834a4ff8f952cb86ec02) these two fields are declared as `nested`. I also have a working query (which essentially is a doubly nested filter on un-analyzed strings) which is shown below and which does work perfectly fine (my actual use-case has an even deeper nesting).

I have two `inner_hits` clauses in the query: the outer work works

**The problem** is that the "inner" `inner_hits` does not work: for the first inner_hits clause we obtain the "real" inner-hits for the `members` field; but for the second `inner_hits` clause I get following result for `members.members` field, which is just wrong (the hits cannot be empty, since then the entire document wouldn't be a hit):

```
      "members.members": {
        "hits": {
          "total": 0,
          "max_score": null,
          "hits": []
        }
      }
```

**Query:**

```
POST nia/condition/_search
{
   "query": {
      "filtered": {
         "query": {
            "match_all": {}
         },
         "filter": {
            "nested": {
               "path": "members",
               "filter": {
                  "bool": {
                     "must": [
                        {
                           "nested": {
                              "path": "members.members",
                              "filter": {
                                 "bool": {
                                    "must": [
                                       {
                                          "term": {
                                             "members.members.findingRef.name": "ImpairedSenseOfTouch"
                                          }
                                       }
                                    ]
                                 }
                              },
                              "inner_hits": {}
                           }
                        }
                     ]
                  }
               },
               "inner_hits": {}
            }
         }
      }
   }
}
```

**Remark:** Replacing the `bool` filter with direct `term` filter does not help either (and it shouldn't matter since entire "sub-documents' are supposed to be given back).