# How to search in ElasticSearch nested objects using NEST

Tags: c#, .net, elasticsearch, nested, nest

I'm trying to search my elasticsearch nested objects by using NEST c# client.
My index name is `people` and my type is `person` in which the `car` field is `nested`.

This is my class:

```
using Nest;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace WebApplication5
{
public class person
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public String fname  { get; set; }
    public String mname { get; set; }
    public String lname { get; set; }
    public String houseno { get; set; }
    [ElasticProperty(Type = FieldType.Nested)]
    public IList<NestedType> car { get; set; } 
    public class NestedType
    {
        public String carname { get; set; }
        public int car_no { get; set; }
        public String color { get; set; }
    }
}

}
```

Now my web application looks something like this:

```
using Elasticsearch.Net;
using Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR;
using Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Configuration;
using Nest;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

namespace WebApplication5
{
public partial class WebForm1 : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    Stopwatch stopwatch = new Stopwatch();
    Uri node;
    ConnectionSettings settings;
    ElasticClient client;
    IList<person> list;
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        node = new Uri("http://localhost:9200");
        settings = new ConnectionSettings(node, defaultIndex:   "people");
        client = new ElasticClient(settings);
        list = new List<person>();

    }

    public IList<person> Search(ref long totalResult, int from,  int size, string searchKeyword)
    {
        list.Clear();
        stopwatch.Start();

        try
        {

            var result = client.Search<person> /*   */


  stopwatch.Start();
  totalResult = result.Total;
  list = result.Hits.Select(t => t.Source).ToList<person>();
  }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            string msg = ex.Message;
        }
 return 
            list;
    }
 protected void TextBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        long totalResult = 0;
        IList<person> List = new List<person>();
        List = Search(ref totalResult, 0, 1000,TextBox1.Text);
        Label1.Text = "" + List.Count + " result(s)"+ " in "+ stopwatch.Elapsed.TotalSeconds+"seconds";
        GridView1.DataSource = List;
        GridView1.DataBind();
        List.Clear();

    }
  }
}
```

Here `searchKeyword` is the the word that i need to search.
I enter it in a search box(webform) in the browser.
The searchKeyword may contain any value which needs to be matched to the value of any field in my table `person`.
If the searchKeyword matches with a nested document then the exact nested document should be returned.
I don't know there is something wrong with my nested query or i actually can't figure out how to use a nested query to do this. Everytime i run the application and search for a value which is actually present in the table,i get zero results.  Please help me figure out how to write the `query` to search in the nested fields and help me in checking if i have written the `class` correctly. 
The query part is Marked as /*    */.
Can anyone help me resolve this?

**UPDATE**
This is my index mapping :

```
POST- people/person/_mapping
{
"person":{
"properties":{
  "car": {
    "type": "nested"
    }
  }
 }
}
```

And my records look like this:

```
POST-people/person
{
"id":1, 
"fname":"aditi",  
"mname":"ananya", 
"lname":"xyz", 
"houseno":"abc",
"car":
 [
  {
   "carname":"fiat",
   "carno":1234,
   "color":"white"
  },

  {
   "carname":"maruti",
   "carno":5678,
   "color":"silver"
  }
 ]
}


POST-people/person
{
"id":2, 
"fname":"robin",  
"mname":"kumar", 
"lname":"sharma", 
"houseno":"efg",
"car":
  [
   {
      "carname":"audi",
      "carno":4321,
      "color":"black"
   },

   {
      "carname":"honda",
      "carno":8765,
      "color":"red"
   },

   {
      "carname":"merecedez",
      "carno":0101,
      "color":"purple"
   }
 ]
}
```

Which means i have 2 records.

**SECOND UPDATE**
I tried this query and it works fine. Though this is not my final query.

```
POST-people/person/_search
{
"_source":false,
"query": {
"filtered": {
  "query": {"match_all": {}},
  "filter": {
    "nested": {
      "path": "car",
      "query":{
        "filtered": {
          "query": { "match_all": {}},
          "filter": {
            "and": [
              {"term": {"car.carname":"mercedez"}},
              {"term": {"car.color":"purple"}}
            ]
          }
        }
      },
"inner_hits":{}
    }
  }
 }
}
}
```

**THIRD UPDATE**
Ok, so now In this case my final query should be :

```
{"_source":false,
"query": {
 "filtered": {
  "query": {"match_all": {}},
  "filter": {
    "nested": {
      "path": "car",
      "filter": {
        "term": {
          "car.carname": "audi"
        }
      }, 
      "inner_hits" : {}
    }
   }
  }
 }
}
```

How do i write this query in .net?
Here,the "_source" and "inner_hits" are important for me because i want to return only the matching nested document and nothing else(i.e. i want to return only the matched nested document and not the other nested documents).
So, can you please help me write the corresponding search query for this?
Moreover, here i'm matching in the `car.carname` field, but i want my application should be able to match for all other sub-fields of the `car` field like `car.carno` and `car.color` and even for all the other top level fields like `id`, `fname` etc.

**FOURTH UPDATE**
Here i have written the search query in .net for my final query that i had mentioned my in **THIRD UPDATE** (please look into my third update).
Can you please check if it is correct?
The corresponding final query in .net which i have written is:

```
(s => s
 .Source(false)
   .Query(query => query.Filtered(filtered => filtered
    .Query(q => q.MatchAll())
      .Filter(f => f.Nested(nf => nf
        .InnerHits()
        .Path(p => p.car)
        .Query(qq => qq.Match(m => m.OnField(g=>g.car.First().carname).Query("audi"))))))));
```

This is what i have written by studying your queries(Thanx a lot for that :) ).  Do check this and tell me if there is anything wrong. But yeah,i'm still unable to retrieve any results.

Answer (score 7):

Try to use nested query.

Let me index some data for test purpose:

```
client.Index(new Person
{
    Id = 1, 
    Car = new List<NestedType> {new NestedType {Carname = "car1"}}
});
client.Index(new Person
{
    Id = 2,
    Car = new List<NestedType> {new NestedType {Carname = "car1"}, new NestedType {Carname = "car2"}}
});
client.Index(new Person
{
    Id = 3,
    Car = new List<NestedType> { new NestedType {Carname = "car2"}}
});

client.Refresh();
```

Now, try this nested query:

```
var searchResponse = client.Search<Person>(s =>
    s.Query(q => q
        .Nested(n => n
            .Path(p => p.Car)
            .Query(qq => qq.Match(m => m.OnField(f => f.Car.First().Carname).Query("car2"))))));
```

Search result:

```
{
   "took": 10,
   "timed_out": false,
   "_shards": {..},
   "hits": {
      "total": 2,
      "max_score": 1.4054651,
      "hits": [
         {
            "_index": "my_index",
            "_type": "person",
            "_id": "2",
            "_score": 1.4054651,
            "_source": {
               "id": 2,
               "car": [
                  {
                     "carname": "car1",
                     "carNo": 0
                  },
                  {
                     "carname": "car2",
                     "carNo": 0
                  }
               ]
            }
         },
         {
            "_index": "my_index",
            "_type": "person",
            "_id": "3",
            "_score": 1,
            "_source": {
               "id": 3,
               "car": [
                  {
                     "carname": "car2",
                     "carNo": 0
                  }
               ]
            }
         }
      ]
   }
}
```

Hope it helps you.

*UPDATE*

Including your formatting:

```
var searchResponse = client.Search<person>(s =>
    s.Query(q => q
        .Nested(n => n
            .Path(p => p.car)
            .Query(qq => qq.Match(m => m.OnField(f => f.car.First().carname).Query("car2"))))));
```

*UPDATE2*

Based on your update, try this query:

```
var searchResponse = client.Search<Person>(s => s
    .Query(query => query.Filtered(filtered => filtered
        .Query(q => q.MatchAll())
        .Filter(f => f.Nested(nf => nf
            .Path(p => p.Car)
            .Filter(filter => filter
                .And(
                    f1 => f1.Term(t => t.Car.First().Carname, "audi"),
                    f2 => f2.Term(t => t.Car.First().Color, "purple"))) 
            )))));
```

which produces this query to elasticsearch:

```
{
  "query": {
    "filtered": {
      "query": {
        "match_all": {}
      },
      "filter": {
        "nested": {
          "filter": {
            "and": {
              "filters": [
                {
                  "term": {
                    "car.carname": "audi"
                  }
                },
                {
                  "term": {
                    "car.color": "purple"
                  }
                }
              ]
            }
          },
          "path": "car"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

*UPDATE3*

With inner hits:

```
var searchResponse = client.Search<Person>(s => s
    .Source(false)
    .Query(query => query.Filtered(filtered => filtered
        .Query(q => q.MatchAll())
        .Filter(f => f.Nested(nf => nf
            .InnerHits()
            .Path(p => p.Car)
            .Filter(filter => filter
                .And(
                    f1 => f1.Term(t => t.Car.First().Carname, "audi"),
                    f2 => f2.Term(t => t.Car.First().Color, "purple")))
            )))));
```

Note: there was bug in elasticsearch 1.5.0 regarding inner hits and filter. [Have a look.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29251994/inner-hits-not-working-with-nested-filter)
Let me know if you need help with retrieving inner hits.

Comment: ...Thankx a lot for answering. actually, I already have records in my elasticsearch database, so, i'm searching within those. but for the query you have given i'm getting errors in the 's' , 'q' and 'f' in the 1st, 2nd and 5th line respectively. Where it says "Cannot convert lambda expression to type 'Nest.ISearchRequest' / 'Nest.IQueryContainer' / 'string' because it is not a delegate type"  respectively for 's', 'q' and 'f'.
 There is also another error for using the first().

Comment: Maybe because I adjusted properties to more ".Net way". Try to use your names: Car -> car, Carname -> carname etc.

Comment: Yes, i had already used my names only. but the thing is i'm not getting any errors now, but when i'm running the web application and searching for a value which is actually present in the carname field, i'm getting zero results. Is there anything wrong with my class design?

Comment: @AditiAnanya may you share index mapping, and code which created index?

Comment: please check my UPDATE. I have shared my index mapping and the records i have. :) and yes, my index creation and record insertion are done through the elasticsearch head plugin .

Comment: Hmm ... Looks fine. So maybe attach also you final query?

Comment: check my second update Rob. I tried that query in the head plugin and that works fine though that is not my final query. My final query would be just matching a particular value and hence returning the results.

Comment: @AditiAnanya maybe my second update will be helpful.

Comment: yes,your update helps. Thankx a lot. see my third update. I have mentioned about my final query there. can you please see if that can be done?? I have explained my requirements too .

Comment: I got it Rob. Understood how to write the query. Thankx a lottt :)
Please check my Fourth Update and tell me if i have written the correct .net query for the JSON query that i had mentioned in my third update(which is my final query).

Comment: @AditiAnanya may you check how looks like search produced by NEST? Use this code ```UTF8Encoding.UTF8.GetString(searchResponse.RequestInformation.Request)```

Comment: @Rob How would you change the query if you wanted to match on more criteria. For ex: carName=audi & carColor=purple & carName=jeep & carColor=yellow. Basically how to match on multiple docs in the nested part.

Comment: @Adrian propably I would go with terms query instead of term. Hope that helps.

Comment: i know this is old post, but i am looking for CRUD operation on Nested Type only, not the main index. thanks in advanced.

Comment: You can use [partial update](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-update.html#_updates_with_a_partial_document) or use [script](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-update.html#_scripted_updates) to do the job.